How can a question that asks if/how a particular sentence is provable in a particular formal theory be more "focused"?
My question that asked if a particular sentence was provable in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory and what would be a good argument showing its provability (a complete proof would be an answer too) was closed as needing more "focus." How can this be any more focused?

Your question was quite a bit longer than what you posted here, and contained three separate links. Don't expect users to have to chase down several internet links to begin to understand you.  Write your question (one question) self-contained.

@amWhy, my question was self-contained. The links were a convenience, disregard them if you like. Of course, the reader was expected to be familiar with the subject the question is about. As always.

@amWhy, as to the remark that "Your question was quite a bit longer than what you posted here" -- do you mean that I should have quoted the entire question here? What for?
